# Spark: why foreach() not work in rdd.foreachPartition?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

My code is below.

```scala
   stream
      .map(x => {
        x.value()
      }).foreachRDD(
        rdd => {
          rdd.foreachPartition(
            (records: Iterator[String]) => {
              println(records.length) // length of records
              records.foreach(
                x => {
                  println(x) // record content
                }
              )
            }
          )
        }
      )
```

The source is Kafka and I use Spark 2.1.1.

I found that the program would only print the length of records if I kept the code `println(records.length)`, but when I removed this line the program printed the record content successfully.

I am confused about which part caused this? The parameter of `rdd.foreachPartition()` is `f: Iterator[T] => Unit` and I think the whole code block after `=>` should be executed, including the `foreach` part.

Do I have any misunderstandings in scala/spark functional programming?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging in IDEA, I thought I found the reason.

It was because the iterator would become empty after calling the `length`.

The `length` source code also mentions this.

> Note:
> Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it was called on. Using it is undefined and subject to change.

As for the reason, I think, if you dive into the source code step by step, you will find that it is just like the java iterator. The reference will point to the next element after calling `next()`, which is implemented by `IndexedSeqLike`.

```scala
    def next(): A = {
      if (index >= end)
        Iterator.empty.next()

      val x = self(index) //updating the pointer
      index += 1
      x
    }
```

I wish I make it clear.